# Grid Control - two colums in one, depend on value

Tags: devexpress, field, gridcontrol

Hello I have grid control (devexpress) with two columns
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTs69.png)

I would like to DONT have column 2 (not visible) and these rows with ticks (in column 2) move to column 1. Rows with no ticks are permanently on false and I dont want user to even see it.

Could you help me how I can do this or Is it even possible?
Thank so much.

Final View [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGCV8.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GridView.CustomRowCellEdit](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.CustomRowCellEdit) event to custom the editor in a column.

if the `column2.Value` is true ,you can set `column1.RepositoryItem` = [RepositoryItemCheckEdit](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit). And you can set `column2.Visible`=false to hide column2